# trying to use variables in javascript outer the function scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i m using node-red and i m injecting some json variables, i can only see them in function scope, how can i use them outer the function.

i've tried angularjs controller but it didn't work, maybe i did not used it correctly

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

  <div>{{msg.payload}}</div>

  <div>{{value}}</div><br>

  <div>{{value1}}</div><br>

  <div>{{value2}}</div><br> // i can see the contents

  <md-button ng-click="send({payload:action()})">

  </md-button>

  <script>
    (function(scope) {

      scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {

        if (msg.payload.image) {

          scope.value2 = msg.payload.image;

        }
        if (msg.payload.text) {

          scope.value1 = msg.payload.text;

        }

        if (msg.payload.volume) {

          scope.value = msg.payload.volume;

        }

        scope.action = function() {

          return [scope.value, scope.value1, scope.value2];

        }

      });

    })(scope);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are only valid and accessible in the scope where they were created (and in "child-scopes").

If you want to have some global variable, you can just create a "global variable" (just google).

But since you are using Angular (though the old "angularjs" and not the new "Angular" version), there are better ways. In Angular (the new one, don't know about the old one) you can create and use something called "service". Those are some sort of global accessible object that can hold many variables and stuff to be used elsewhere in the code.

BUT: Depending on your use-case here, you may also create the variables on the outer angular-component and insert/pass them into the child-component. This way both can use and access it. Read more about binding/2-way-binding for that purpose.